# $_POST empty in PHP file but call it with POST variables in the URL

Tags: php, html, arrays, url, post

I call my php file in the browser with "...test.php?text=Hello" but the `$_POST` variable stays empty (also `print_r($_POST)` returns `array()` ).

Why? Do I need to activate the post variable or something?

Thanks.

Comment: $_REQUEST['text'] also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables passed in through the URL end up inside `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

`$_POST` contains variables parsed by reading the HTTP request *[body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_body_data)* when the *[method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)* is POST. In this case the method is not POST and there is also no request body.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the variable through the URL you use $_GET.
Also, you will access the variable with:

```
$_GET['text']
```

This is a array that is sent through and you need to specify what item in the array you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

`...test.php?text=hello` passes data via the GET method (accessible via `$_GET` in the processing script).

`$_POST` gets populated by forms or cURL access (when the transfer method is defined as "post")